# Object of class could not be converted to string error

Tags: php

I am receiving the following error below on the object's function in Smarty and I am unaware of how to resolve the issue.

Error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class users_class could not be converted to string
```

This is the following object and function of the object I am using.

```
class users_class
{
    public function fetchUser(array $conditions)
    {
        $db = Core::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".USERS." WHERE ";
        $i=0;
        $params = array();
        //$where = array();
        foreach ($conditions as $column => $value)
        {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.-_]+$/', $column)) {
                if ($i!=0) {
                    $sql .= " AND ";
                }
                $sql .= "$column = ?";
                $params[] = $value;
                $i++;
            }
        }           
        //$sql .= implode(' AND ', $where);
        //$sql .= " order by title asc";    
        $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(array_values($params));
        return $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);               
    }
}
```

This is the call in Smarty:

```
 {section name=ststval loop=$ststres}
    {if $ststres[ststval].type == 2}
       {assign var='udatas' value="$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id));"}
```

Comment: Try removing the quotes surrounding the expression, so `value="$userObj->fetchUser ..."` becomes `value=$userObj->fetchUser ...`

Comment: After doing that I received the following error.  `'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "./templates/profile_left.tpl" on line 149 "{assign var='udatas' value=$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))}" - Unexpected "=>", expected one of: "","" , ")`

Comment: Why the negative point and what was edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the __toString() method to the object. Apparently, the object just has to return a string. This was confusing to me because I didn't know what it should return and directions were not clear on php.net. For a person learning PHP things need to be explained when asked for help not pointed to the same articles everyone reads when learning PHP. I believe we come asking for help on websites like these because we require explanations from people with higher knowledge. I call it lazy and unhelpful!

```
class users_class
{

    protected $users_class='';

    public function __toString() {
   
        return (string)$this->users_class;
    }


    public function fetchUser(array $conditions)
    {
        $db = Core::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".USERS." WHERE ";
        $i=0;
        $params = array();
        //$where = array();
        foreach ($conditions as $column => $value)
        {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.-_]+$/', $column)) {
                if ($i!=0) {
                    $sql .= " AND ";
                }
                $sql .= "$column = ?";
                $params[] = $value;
                $i++;
            }
        }           
        //$sql .= implode(' AND ', $where);
        //$sql .= " order by title asc";    
        $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(array_values($params));
        return $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert an object to a string in this way, you need a magic [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method defined

Comment: From what I see here, you have to just implement that method and can return any string from there .. it doesn't seem to matter what the actual value is, as the next post below shows an empty string being returned from the impl'd method.  In my case, just to be safe - I make sure I have unique strings between objects. ::   public function __toString() {
 
  return (string)$this->action;
 }

Comment: @gnB Yes, you can return whatever you want from a magic __toString() method, as long as it is a string value

Comment: Right, and then Smarty is happy if he needs to dump the var as a string. And you can still access the full object graph, the __toString() has nothing to do with that .. at first I thought somehow Smarty would mutate the object based on the __toString() .. that there was some inherent relationship between how the object is received and what is in the __toString() method.  This IS NOT the case I found .. what it is, is that Smarty can handle the full object on its own.  And then for its .tpl layer, it *does* need a __toString() impl. (..kinda along the lines of Java .toString())

Comment: Well the original poster of this question did say I was "lazy and unhelpful"

Comment: I gotta say, it was his post below that got me to actually try the code.. but yea, the comment there is too negative.. leaves me a bad taste. Having read & tried the excerpt he listed, I was able to understand your post. I agree the delivery there leaves much to be desired, but also agree a small code example would have been really helpful for this post especially.. 'specially for some of us newbs :). 90%+ of the time I scan for replies that have an actual snippet I can quickly try. I've had same gripe myself.. but as wise man said: "Better to speak gently in pursuing one's aims" .. right?! :)

Comment: The fine line between spoon-feeding an answer, and just providing enough information for somebody to learn for themselves. With hindsight, I should have provided an example; but I don't generally revisit questions after the day they're posted unless I have something really valuable to add to an answer